# Operator overflow with two types

Tags: overflow, operator-keyword

I got a problem regarding operators.

```
class Fraction{
public:

    Bruch(int z = 0, int n = 1);
    void operator*(Fraction &b);
    void calculate(char operation, Fraction &b);

private:
}

void Fraction::calculate(char operation, Fraction &b) {
    switch(operation) {
    case '*': operator*(b); break;
} 

Fraction::Fraction(int z, int n){                                       
    zaehler = z;
    nenner = n;
}

void Fraction::operator*(Fraction &b){
    zaehler = zaehler * b.zaehler;
    nenner = nenner * b.nenner;
}

int main(){

Fraction a(7, 5);
lont int b = 3.0;

Fraction d = a*b;
}
```

---

I want to be able to use the operator* not only with two members of class Fraction but also with one of type long int.

Error: "no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘long int’ to ‘Fraction&’"

Anybody some advice?